# How to remove simple text from HTML/HAML

Tags: html, css, haml

Simple question. Under my Inspect Element, I see this pesky text next to an image I'm trying to align with CSS. I found where the text in question comes from but I am still unable to get rid of it and its simply annoying me.

The contents of said quotes are located in this partial.

```
%div{:style=>"clear:both;font-size:90%;"}
 %div{:style=>"float:right;text-align:right;margin-left:15px;"}
   %a{:href=>project_url(widget.project), :style=> 'color:#999; text-decoration:none;', :target=>"_blank"}

     more at


     %img{:style=>"border:none; width:48px: height:12px;", :src=>widget_ohloh_logo_url}
 %a{:style=>"color:#999", :href=>project_url(widget.project), :target=>"_blank", :title => widget.project.name}
   - if widget.project.best_analysis && widget.project.best_analysis.logged_at
     - updated_time = ", updated #{widget.project.best_analysis.logged_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y")}"
   = "#{widget_project_name_truncated(widget)}#{updated_time}"
```

I've replaced the more at text with

```
%p more at
```

but still the text persists and is not wrapped as a p tag to modify with CSS.

How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu must check the html for `<figure></figure>` inside figure there must be a `<caption></caption>`,
del the caption tag to get ride of the text..